# Using if statement in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

For the following scenario:

```
Id  Total points    Correct Trends
1       12                8
2       12                4
3       10                5
4       10                7
5       10                2
```

Lets say I am the person with `Id = 3`.

I want to calculate the Ids which have Total points and Correct Trends greater than me.

If I use the below query then I will not get the user with `Id=2` as his `Correct Trends` is less then mine.

```
var allAbove = (from item in userQuery
               where (item.Id!= myData.Id && 
               item.TotalPoints >= (myData.TotalPoints) &&
               item.CorrectTrends >= (myData.CorrectTrends) )
```

**I am not able to find a way to check that when Total Points are equal then look for Correct Trends other wise check for Total Points only**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is actually straight forward:

```
var allAbove = (from item in userQuery
           where (item.Id!= myData.Id && 
           item.TotalPoints > myData.TotalPoints ||
           (item.TotalPoints == myData.TotalPoints && 
           item.CorrectTrends >= myData.CorrectTrends)));
```

It checks if either total points is greater **or** total points are equal *and* correct trends are greater.

Comment: It was too easy but my mind is locked at the moment. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use `CorrectTrends` only for tie breaking, the correct expression should look like this:

```
item.Id!= myData.Id && (
       item.TotalPoints > myData.TotalPoints      // "Wins" on total points
||    (item.TotalPoints == myData.TotalPoints     // Same total points,
    && item.CorrectTrends > myData.CorrectTrends) // but higher correct trends
)
```

Note that `>=` need to be replaced with `>` to avoid items with ties.

Answer (score 0):

Since i like method chain more:

```
var you = items.Where(x=>x.Id == myId).FirstOrDefault();
var allAbove = items.Where(x=>x.Id!=you.Id)
.Where(x=>x.TotalPoint>you.TotalPoints || x.CorrectTrends>you.CorrectTrends);
```

I'll let you do the null checking :)